# How to cancel Future.wait (in dart)?

Tags: flutter, dart, future, dart-async

I have two Future functions which I run asynchronously:

```
List<Future<bool>> jobs = [];
jobs.add(asyncFunction1());
jobs.add(asyncFunction2());
jobsResults = await Future.wait(jobs);
```

If asyncFunction1 returns false - I want to finish current procedure (for not to wait asyncFunction2).
How to do it?

Comment: We cannot able to cancel the Future  So, Need manual time out or need to change to Stream
Please check this Document 
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-cancel-a-future-in-flutter-bb1f7ad19381#:~:text=We%20know%20that%20we%20can,listen%20to%20future%20as%20stream.

Comment: In general you have no meta-access to the event queue in your isolate.  This might be a bit heavyweight, but you *can* abort another isolate, although I don't think anyone is doing that in practice.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a standard way of doing this but a "hacky" way would be to have the functions throw errors if false. You could then utilize the `eagerError=True` (parameter for Future.wait). That will return immediately on the first error received.

Docs: https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.3.1/dart-async/Future/wait.html

Comment: While specifying `eagerError: true` will make the `Future.wait` to complete immediately when one future completes with an error, does it make the other futures to cancel their operations?

Comment: Their operations won't be cancelled but the Future will not wait on them.